# Find lower bound of probability value using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

Given density function of random variabel $X$ is $f(x) = 3x^2$, for $0 \lt x \lt 1$. Use Chebyshev's inequality to find lower bound of probability value :

1. $P(5/8 \lt x \lt 7/8)$
2. $P(1/2 \lt x \lt 1)$

Comment: Why do you need the Chebishev inequality when the probabilities can be exactly calculated: $$P(\frac{5}{8}<X<\frac{7}{8})=3\int_{\frac{5}{8}}^{\frac{7}{8}}x^2dx=\frac{7^3-5^3}{8^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your density function matches the distribution $Beta(3, 1)$ which has mean $\mu = E(X) = 3/4$ and $\sigma^2 = 3/80 =  0.0375$, so $\sigma \approx  0.1936.$ You can verify all this with elementary calculus.

Then $P(5/8 < X < 7/8) = P(|X = \mu| < 1/8),$ which is in a form
convenient for the use of Chebyshev's inequality. (How many standard deviations is 1/8; that is, if $k\sigma = 1/8,$ what is $k?$ The
answer will be trivial.)

Similarly, $P(1/2 < X < 1) = P(|X - \mu| < 1/4).$ Here the Chebyshev
bound is not trivial.

In practice, Chebyshev's inequality is seldom useful for setting
bounds. Here, @zoli has noted that simple calculus gives you an
exact answer. Even when integration is not so simple, software can
give an answer to many such problems. For example, in R statistical
software the exact answer to (a) can be obtained by the first statement below, giving the same result as in the Comment, as computed in the second statement.

```
 diff(pbeta(c(5/8, 7/8), 3, 1))
 ## 0.4257813
 (7^3 - 5^3)/8^3
 ## 0.4257813
```

Nevertheless, Chebyshev's inequality is extremely useful in theoretical proofs, not least to prove the (Weak) Law of Large Numbers, and
so it is an inequality you have to know. This simple exercise
may help you remember what it says, even if it has no apparent
practical use.